# web3js can't connect to private network

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript

Beginner in ethereum i started a private network using the following command

```
sudo geth --fast --cache 512 --ipcpath ~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc --networkid 1234 --rpcport "8081"  --datadir ~/.ethereum_private  console[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

in my node js application

```
var Web3 = require('web3');



if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

console.log(web3.isConnected());
```

`web3.isConnected()` return always `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your command, you set RPC port to 8081
In your code, you try to connect to port 8545
So change `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));`
To `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8081"));`

Moreover, with web3 1.0.0, the isConnected() method won't return true unless you already tried to connect to the node. It's still in beta, so you can't rely on this method yet.

Comment: changed the port but still the same false\,web3 version is `0.19.0`

Comment: When i changed the port name  Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined

Comment: Add the "--rpc" flag to your command to launch geth

Comment: yeah its worked:)